# only fetch one node element value in xml parsing?

Tags: android

I am parsing this xml-

```
   <school title="The Clifton School" icon="" browserBackButtonTitle = "Clifton App" navBarColor = "#7eb432">

<screen id = "1" backgroundColor = "" backgroundImg = "" templateId = "12" hasNavigationBar = "0" hasTabBar = "1" >

    <navigation-bar title = "" color = "#7eb432" backButtonTitle = "Back">
        <!--<navigation-item type = "1" action = "" />-->
    </navigation-bar>

    <tab-bar numberOfTabs = "4" >
        <tab-bar-item title = "Home" image = "tab_home.png" linkedScreen = "101" />
        <tab-bar-item title = "Calendar" image = "tab_calendar.png" linkedScreen = "102" />
        <tab-bar-item title = "Menu" image = "tab_menu.png" linkedScreen = "604" />
        <tab-bar-item title = "Directions" image = "tab_directions.png" linkedScreen = "401" />
        <tab-bar-item title = "Contact" image = "tab_contact.png" linkedScreen = "206" />
    </tab-bar>

</screen>

<screen id = "101" backgroundColor = "" backgroundImg = "HomeScreenBg.png" templateId = "11" hasNavigationBar = "0" hasTabBar = "1" 
cresInfoButton = "1" >

    <navigation-bar title = "" color = "#7eb432" backButtonTitle = "Back">
        <!--<navigation-item type = "1" action = "" />-->
    </navigation-bar>
    <button-view yOffset = "100" spacing = "6" />
    <button width = "274" height = "30" image = "blue_home_button.png" action = "201" textColor = "#ffffff">About The Clifton School</button>
    <button width = "274" height = "30" image = "blue_home_button.png" action = "102" textColor = "#ffffff">School Calendar</button>
    <button width = "274" height = "30" image = "blue_home_button.png" action = "103" textColor = "#ffffff">Admissions</button>
    <button width = "274" height = "30" image = "red_home_button.png" action = "601" textColor = "#ffffff">Parent Corner</button>
    <button width = "274" height = "30" image = "green_home_button.png.png" action = "301" textColor = "#ffffff">Request Information</button>
    <button width = "274" height = "30" image = "green_home_button.png.png" action = "401" textColor = "#ffffff">Directions</button>
    <button width = "274" height = "30" image = "green_home_button.png.png" action = "112" textColor = "#ffffff">Tell a Friend about Clifton</button>

</screen>

<screen id = "102" backgroundColor = "#dedede" backgroundImg = "InnerPages_BG.png" templateId = "4" hasNavigationBar = "1" hasTabBar = "1" >

    <navigation-bar title = "School Calendar" color = "#7eb432" backButtonTitle = "Back">
        <!--<navigation-item type = "1" action = "" />-->
    </navigation-bar>

    <table-view noOfSection = "1">  <!-- TableView -->
        <table-section title = "" noOfRows = "3">
            <table-row isClickable = "1" action= "113" hasAccessory = "1" backgroundColor = "#d5eebb" textColor = "#000000">Clifton Campus</table-row>
            <table-row isClickable = "1" action= "114" hasAccessory = "1" backgroundColor = "#d5eebb" textColor = "#000000">Clairmont Campus</table-row>
        </table-section>
    </table-view>

</screen>

<screen id = "103" backgroundColor = "#dedede" backgroundImg = "InnerPages_BG.png" templateId = "4" hasNavigationBar = "1" hasTabBar = "1" >

    <navigation-bar title = "Admissions" color = "#7eb432" backButtonTitle = "Back">
        <!--<navigation-item type = "1" action = "" />-->
    </navigation-bar>

    <table-view noOfSection = "1">  <!-- TableView -->
        <table-section title = "" noOfRows = "1">
            <table-row isClickable = "1" action= "107" hasAccessory = "1" backgroundColor = "#d5eebb" textColor = "#000000">Enrollment Process</table-row>
        </table-section>
        <table-section title = "" noOfRows = "3">
            <table-row isClickable = "1" action= "104" hasAccessory = "1" backgroundColor = "#d5eebb" textColor = "#000000">Tour</table-row>
            <table-row isClickable = "1" action= "105" hasAccessory = "1" backgroundColor = "#d5eebb" textColor = "#000000">Tuition</table-row>
            <table-row isClickable = "1" action= "106" hasAccessory = "1" backgroundColor = "#d5eebb" textColor = "#000000">Enrollment Application</table-row>
        </table-section>
    </table-view>

</screen>

<screen id = "104" backgroundColor = "#dedede" backgroundImg = "InnerPages_BG.png" templateId = "6" hasNavigationBar = "1" hasTabBar = "1" >

    <navigation-bar title = "Tour" color = "#7eb432" backButtonTitle = "Back">
        <!--<navigation-item type = "1" action = "" />-->
    </navigation-bar>

    <table-view noOfSection = "1">  <!-- TableView -->
        <table-section title = "" noOfRows = "1">
        <table-row isClickable = "0" action= "" height = "345" >http://www.crescerance.com/school/clifton/Tours.html</table-row>
        </table-section>
    </table-view>

</screen>

<screen id = "105" backgroundColor = "#dedede" backgroundImg = "InnerPages_BG.png" templateId = "6" hasNavigationBar = "1" hasTabBar = "1" >
    <navigation-bar title = "Tuition" color = "#7eb432" backButtonTitle = "Back">
        <!--<navigation-item type = "1" action = "" />-->
    </navigation-bar>

    <table-view noOfSection = "1">  <!-- TableView -->
        <table-section title = "" noOfRows = "1">
        <table-row isClickable = "0" action= "" height = "345" >http://www.crescerance.com/school/clifton/Tuition.html</table-row>
        </table-section>
    </table-view>
</screen>

<screen id = "106" backgroundColor = "#dedede" backgroundImg = "" templateId = "7" hasNavigationBar = "1" hasTabBar = "1" >
    <navigation-bar title = "Enrollment Application" color = "#7eb432" backButtonTitle = "Back">
        <!--<navigation-item type = "1" action = "" />-->
    </navigation-bar>

    <browser-view>  <!-- BrowserView -->
        <url>http://www.thecliftonschool.org/docs/Enrollment%20APPLICATION.pdf</url>
    </browser-view>
</screen>
```

but it is not working firstly I make 5 pojo classes in which take properties are nodes of xml describe above.
     for that I using this class for parsing but fetch only one node values-

```
boolean isSchool = false;
boolean isSCreen = false;
boolean isNavBar = false;
boolean istabbar = false;
Context theContext;

Map<String,String> schoolmap,screenmap,navimap,tabbarmap,tabbaritem;

public static School objschool         = null;
public static Screen objscreen         = null;
public static NavigationBar objnavBar  = null;
public static ScreenTabBar objtabBar   = null;
public static TabBarItem objtabBaritem = null;

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException
        {
        super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);
        //ArrayList<Screen> screens = new ArrayList<Screen>();

        if (localName.equals("school"))
         {
             isSchool=true;
            objschool = new School();
            /** Start */    
            String title = attributes.getValue("title");
            String icon = attributes.getValue("icon");
            String browserBackButtonTitle = attributes.getValue("browserBackButtonTitle");
            String school_navBarColor = attributes.getValue("navBarColor");

            objschool.setTitle(title);
            objschool.setIcon(icon);
            objschool.setBrowserBackButtonTitle(browserBackButtonTitle);
            objschool.setNavBarColor(school_navBarColor);

        }
        else if (localName.equals("screen"))
        {
             isSCreen = true;
         /** Get attribute value */
            objscreen = new Screen();
            String screen_id = attributes.getValue("id");
            String screen_backgroundColor = attributes.getValue("backgroundColor");
            String screen_backgroundImg = attributes.getValue("backgroundImg");
            String screen_templateId = attributes.getValue("templateId");
            String screen_hasNavigationBar = attributes.getValue("hasNavigationBar");
            String screen_hasTabBar = attributes.getValue("hasTabBar");

            objscreen.setId(screen_id);
            objscreen.setBackgroundColor(screen_backgroundColor);
            objscreen.setBackgroundImg(screen_backgroundImg);
            objscreen.setTemplateId(screen_templateId);
            objscreen.setHasNavigationBar(screen_hasNavigationBar);
            objscreen.setHasTabBar(screen_hasTabBar);
            //screens.add(objscreen);
        }
        else if (localName.equals("navigation-bar"))
        {
            objnavBar = new NavigationBar();
            String navititle = attributes.getValue("title");
            String navicolor = attributes.getValue("color");
            String navibackButtonTitle = attributes.getValue("backButtonTitle");
            objnavBar.setTitlelist(navititle);
            objnavBar.setColorlist(navicolor);
            objnavBar.setBackButtonTitlelist(navibackButtonTitle);
        }
        else if (localName.equals("tab-bar"))
        {
            objtabBar = new ScreenTabBar();
            tabbarmap.put("numberOfTabs",attributes.getValue("numberOfTabs"));

        }
        else if (localName.equals("tab-bar-item"))
        {
            objtabBaritem = new TabBarItem();
            tabbarmap.put("Title",attributes.getValue("title"));
            tabbarmap.put("Image",attributes.getValue("image"));
            tabbarmap.put("LinkedScreen",attributes.getValue ("linkedScreen"));
        }
             //           objschool.screenlist = screens;
}

@Override
 public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)throws S    AXException
    {
    super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);

    /** set value */
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("school") && isSchool && isSCreen)
     {
        objschool.setScreenlist(objscreen);
        isSchool=false;
        isSCreen = false;
     }
      else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("screen")&& isSCreen && isNavBar)
      {
          objscreen.setObjlistofNB(objnavBar);
          isSCreen = false;
          isNavBar = false;
      }
      else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("navigation-bar"))
      {
          isNavBar=false;  
      }
}
 @Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.characters(ch, start, length);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are creating new object every time at the start of the element. If the element name is same it will create a new Object to store data of attributes under that element hence losing the previous object. solution for this should be that You should create ArrayList of the Object to store and add the Object into it. For eg:

```
public ArrayList<objscreen> screens = null;
```

and inside of startElement:

```
if (localName.equals("screen"))
    {
         isSCreen = true;
     /** Get attribute value */
        objscreen = new Screen();
        objscreen.setId(attributes.getValue("id"));
        objscreen.setBackgroundColor(attributes.getValue("backgroundColor"));
        objscreen.setBackgroundImg(attributes.getValue("backgroundImg"));
        objscreen.setTemplateId(attributes.getValue("templateId"));
        objscreen.setHasNavigationBar(attributes.getValue("hasNavigationBar"));
        objscreen.setHasTabBar(attributes.getValue("hasTabBar"));

        if(screens ==null)
      screens =new ArrayList<objscreen>();
        screens.add(objscreen);
    }
```